# ViewPager2 left and right padding area Swipe or Click not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

When I swipe ViewPager2 selected item its working fine, But when I touched the left and right padding area of viewpage2, Swipe event not working.

```
binding.viewPager.apply {
            adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this@ViewPagerActivity, itemList)
            clipToPadding = false
            clipChildren = false
            offscreenPageLimit = 3
            val recyclerView = getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView
            recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            setCurrentItem(0, false)
            setPageTransformer(DepthPageTransformer())
        }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarLayout">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingStart="90dp"
            android:paddingEnd="90dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

check : https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples > ViewPager2 > PreviewPagesActivity this code

use recyclerView in Viewpager2

```
binding.viewPager.apply{
   val recyclerView = getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView
   recyclerView.apply{
      setPadding(leftPaddingValue,0,rightPaddingValue,0)
      clipToPadding = false
   }
```

}

that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is the intended behavior.

You did not explain, why you would need padding. So we can only assume a solution.

You could remove the padding from the `ViewPager2` and instead add it to its containing views.

Comment: I need to show selected item at center and previous and next item should be visible at left and right of selected item, That is why I added padding 90dp left & right.